# Numerical integration with a Dirac delta function in integrand

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, dirac-delta

I have an equation that involves a numerical integral using a successive application of the trapezoidal rule between points in the original code. I am trying to solve a problem which has a Dirac delta function in the integrand, instead of the usual factors for which the code was initially written. Ideally (theoretically), the effect of a Dirac delta function is that the integral is equal to the value of the integrands (apart from Dirac delta) at the point where the Dirac delta is located. But, having a Dirac delta with a finite resolution of the numerical method means that the Dirac delta has a finite width (which is a triangle between one step before the location and one step afterward). So, in the trapezoidal method, should I take into account the width of the Dirac delta? The simple math of the trapezoidal rule would suggest so, but I am not 100% convinced.

Comment: You should split the integral into two parts and add the discontinuity introduced by the distribution at that point.

Comment: But the integrals are zero before and after that point. So the only relevance is the value of the function on the interval. No?

Comment: You haven't given enough information to guess what you are doing. But if you have an integral of the form $\int_a^b f(t) \delta(t-t_0) dt$ (with $t_0 \in (a,b)$) then I would compute $\int_a^{t_0}f(t)dt + f(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^b f(t)dt$.

Comment: But, theoretically, the integral that you have is equal to $f(t_0)$. How can this be equal to the approximation that you have given? Also, the internal that you have taken is the right form of the equation that I have.

Comment: My apologies, I meant to write $\int_a^b f(t) (1+\delta(t-t_0)) dt$. The point was just to add extra 'time points' to the integration.

Comment: Oh, that's quite alright.  But, my integral is the form that you had previously.